# React js Change Field specifying the attribute name

Tags: reactjs, object, input, react-state

I have attributes in the state, I would like to ensure that by specifying the function the attribute name changes the value contained in the state.

It seems to work, the problem that if I have an object of this type in the state:

```
companyInfo: {
  name: "",
  vatNumber: "",
  legalRepresentative: ""
}
```

It does not work properly, as the code is now set in the state in this case a new attribute is created.

So I'd like to do something like this:

```
handleChangeField("companyInfo.name")
```

It is changed to the state atrribute name of the obj companyInfo that is in the state.

Can you give me some advice?

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-2kg80)

Code:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactJson from "react-json-view";

class Todo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "email0",
      role: "role0",
      companyInfo: {
        name: "",
        vatNumber: "",
        legalRepresentative: ""
      }
    };
  }

  returnStateElement = (...elements) => {
    const copy = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    return elements.reduce((obj, key) => ({ ...obj, [key]: copy[key] }), {});
  };

  handleChangeField = field => evt => {
    let state = {};
    state[field] = evt.target.value;
    this.setState(state);
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    let el = this.returnStateElement(
      "name",
      "email",
      "vatNumber",
      "legalRepresentative",
      "role"
    );
    let { name, email, legalRepresentative, vatNumber, role } = el;
    let dataSender = {};

    dataSender.email = email;
    dataSender.role = role;
    dataSender.companyInfo = {};
    dataSender.companyInfo.name = name;
    dataSender.companyInfo.legalRepresentative = legalRepresentative;
    dataSender.companyInfo.vatNumber = vatNumber;
    console.log(this.state);
    //console.log(dataSender)
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.handleChangeField("email")} />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input onChange={this.handleChangeField("companyInfo.name")} />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button onClick={() => this.handleSubmit()}>send</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <ReactJson src={this.state} theme="solarized" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I came up with a much better answer where one mutates the specific key of the `oldState` using a reduce. Less code, much more elegant and should work at any object depth.

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-3cfm0)

```
setNestedField(object, fields, newValue) {
   fields.reduce((acc, field, index) => {
     if (index === fields.length - 1) {
       acc[field] = newValue;
     }
     return acc[field];
   }, object);

   return object;
 }
 handleChangeField = field => evt => {
   const fields = field.split(".");
   let oldState = this.state;

   const newState = this.setNestedField(
     { ...oldState },
     fields,
     evt.target.value
   );

   this.setState(newState);
 };
```

**OLD ANSWER**

`handleChangeFields` looks like this:

```
handleChangeField = field => evt => {
    //first you split by '.' to get all the keys
    const fields = field.split(".").reverse();

    // you'll need the previous state
    let oldState = this.state;

    let newState = fields.reduce((acc, value, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
       // you add the event value to the first key
        acc[value] = evt.target.value;
        return acc;
      }

      //copy acc to use it later
      const tmp = { ...acc };

      //delete previous key added to acc 
      delete acc[fields[index - 1]];

      acc[value] = { ...oldState[value], ...tmp };
      return acc;

  }, {});
    this.setState(newState);
  };
```

What's going on step by step in the reduce function, if you do `handleChangeField('company.name')` with `evt.target.value = "Big Corp"`:

1) you get the array `['name','company']`

2) you go in the reduce function

- when `index = 0`, `acc = {}`, `key='name'` => `{name: 'Big Corp'}`
- when `index=1`, `acc= {name: 'Big Corp'}`,`key='company'` => `acc = { company: {name: 'Big Corp'}, name: 'BigCorp}` so before returning we delete the previous `key` (name here) to return => `{ company: {name: 'Big Corp'}`

Comment: It seems to work but look here, if I add another layer, last input field, a strange thing happens, an attractiveness of that object is eliminated: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-uduod

Comment: Indeed, I found a better way to achieve this

Comment: Two last things, according to you there is a way to make it work also with arrays, example (companyInfo.el.ol.ar [1]):
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-kz0w3

As you can see from the code I have a function called returnStateElement, which should return only the attributes of the state I want, I'm having some problems, you could take a look, to know where I'm doing wrong:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-ebldv

Comment: it's going to far :). If you go with such complex object, I would recomment to use both `lodash.set` and `lodash.get` packages. They will make your life easier.